# Node.js client 404 not found with Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, http-status-code-404

I'm about to lear Angular2 so I'm pretty new to this.

What I want to do is to build a little WebApp to controle my Philips Hue lights. So thats why I use the [Huejay client on Node.js](https://github.com/sqmk/huejay).

I cloned the quickstart projekt from Angular 2 and install Node.js and also Huejay.

I just added some lines from the Readme of the Huejay Github page.
But if I try to run this the commandline already tells me that huejey is not found.
[image]

In the werbbrowser console I get sometimes the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and sometimes

```
GET http://localhost:3000/huejay 404 (Not Found)
```

The huejay files are available in my node_modules folder. 
Beacuse I'm new to this I don't know if I have to start the huejay sepereatly (?) or do I forgot to import something at the right place or is it something else?
I think this should be not a big deal for someone with experience in node.js/angular2

Comment: huejay seems to be a node library what is the relevance of angular here? How do you use this lib in your project?

Comment: As I sayed I'm new to Angular2, so I'm not sure if I need some import lines in Angular for the client

Comment: No no I asked because I don't know how to use huejay. I don't know its relationship with angular so if you can elaborate the topic more we can solve it in a combined effort.

Comment: I'm stupid sorry. I was thinking again about the hole thing. But this will not work. There is no relationship between angular and huejay. This is just for node.js. I don't think you can use that as a kind of lib in your angular 2 App. I'm sorry

Comment: No need to apologize :-) We've all been there.